# absolutely positioned content is not displayed inside angular ui-router ui-view

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular-ui-router, css-position

I have here plunkr which shows the issue I am facing.Basically I am trying to do create a scroll bar for middle div element, have all three div's fit inside the page.

This approach works fine if I use it as html page, but when I use it inside ui-view, the content inside '#content-scroll' does not show up, if I remove position:absolute from CSS, it displays, but doesn't display scroll bars.

Basically I just want to know how can I have the content display?

How can this be resolved?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkGafJ8cS6VG6lfS9SJY?p=preview

```
#content-scroll {
position: absolute;
top: 0; bottom: 0;
left: 0; right: 0;
overflow: auto;}
```

Here is the example of same page that works inside html

http://jsfiddle.net/sA5fD/8/

Comment: Why use `display:table-row` to wrap block elements?

Comment: thats how i can create scrollable div

Comment: Haven't narrowed down problem 100% but adding `height:100%` in dev tools live css to container and #content helps. Don't see where yet but might be an `overflow:hidden` somewhere.

Comment: there isn't overflow:hidden anywhere. can you post plunkr, cause it doesn't do for me

Comment: Lost what I did when I refreshed. But all I did was start adding `height:100%` to various elements since highlighter didn't show them being very tall. The content did appear

Comment: got your answer ua_boaz?

Comment: i took a different approach, too many issues with this

Answer (score 1):

`absolute` positioned elements behave according to it's parents.

If we give `bottom:0; top:0;` to an absolutely positioned element it will select the `bottom` and `top` of it's parent. So:

1. Your previous example it is working since the parent have 100% height.
2. Inside `ui-view` it will not work it doesn't have an explicit `height` to it.

There's more than one solution to this problem. For example I applied a `min-height` to the parent `#content` and changed it's display property. I suppose you have `#content` only used for this scrollbar content. Othewise you have to apply special class to the element.

```
#content {
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  background:#8f8;
  min-height: 90vh;
}
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5vl0AN3WwtUJmDiNtNdL?p=preview

Comment: well i am trying to avoid hardcoding viewport height, since in this example i am using only one level of ui-view, in my real application i have multiple levels of ui-views, and i want them to take the height of their parent. And also i have realized that 90vh doesn't work well on different screen sizes. And i have to really avoid scroll bars

Comment: If you want scrollbar in a absolutely positioned element and the parent height is 0, you need to explicitly give height to the element. (90vh or 300px that's our decision). I have changed my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: can you check in internet explorer and firefox? it doesn't show any content

Comment: Which versions? You know IEs are a headache anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess This would solve your problem.

```
 html { height: 100%; }
    body {      
        padding:0 0;
        margin:0 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #main {
        display:table;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    #header, #footer {
        display:table-row;
        background:#88f;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }

    #content {
        display:table-cell;
        height:100vh;

        background:#8f8;
    }

    #content-scroll-wrap {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #content-scroll {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; bottom: 0;
        left: 0; right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: i want to to fit the page to full page, not 100px

Comment: I adjusted its height according to the screen height.. So it will now cover the full page.

Comment: alright.. I was just wondering for the mark as correct because i just realized today that a lot of my answers are on such questions which has no correct answer marked. @ua_boaz